# please anyone can give me the link of eclipse for AIX6.1 64bit

Tags: eclipse, aix

I tried so much but i didn't get eclipse for AIX6.1, please anyone can give me the link of eclipse for AIX6.1 64bit, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To find Eclipse for less common platforms, you have to go to the Eclipse platform download page.

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

Then pick a release. The latest currently is 4.4.1, so...

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.4.1-201409250400/

Then grab one of the Eclipse SDK packages. This will give you basic Eclipse with Java tools. You will need to install other plugins you need.